# creating a data fame with only matching numbers

Tags: frame

can you please help me with writing this code in R?
For example, if I have  a dataset with 3 rows with several numbers as below,

"1 2 3 4 5"

"2 1 3 8 7"

"3 1 2 4  5"

From that, I want to crate a new data set keeping only the numbers that match with other raw numbers only , it would appear as something like below

"1 2 3"

"2 1 3"

"3 1 2"

How can I do that? I was thinking to use "AND" function in a "if" loop, but I don't know how to make r go through each different column to get the matching numbers that will match each raw number of all the data set, please let me know any ideas, Thanks